# rewrite subdomain url to www apache php (using slim framework)

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, slim

I have a website in angular using a api. Now i want to create automated landing pages.

My api url is made like this (https://) system.mydomain.com/api - its a rest api using slim framework

now i have created routes for the landing pages like (https://) system.mydomain.com/content/seo-name-of-item

this works but i dont want to show "system.mydomain.com" in this case (so in the URI "content") but then i want it to be (https://) mydomain.com/content/seo-name-of-item or/and (https://) www.mydomain.com/content/seo-name-of-item

what is the best approach to get this behaviour?

Comment: Keep in mind that you need separate valid ssl certificates for the three host names `system.mydomain.com`, `mydomain.com` and `www.mydomain.com`. Or a "wildcard certificate" which is expensive.

Comment: Best approach? Well, you implement rewriting rules doing either an external redirect (that changes the URL visible in the browser) or you use the internal proxy module to proxy requests between separate http hosts (URL and host name do _not_ change in the browser).

Comment: i have a wildcard certificate for my domain

Comment: well yes i can redirect to another URL from that url but all the logic is done in system.mydomain.com/content/something - this is a route made in slim framework, and it works i just dont want that visitors see the system. if i redirect i have to do the logic in a seperate folder loosing all my power from the slim framework

Comment: I can't follow there. Even _if_ you do an external redirection you can without issue add some internal rewrites for the resulting request which map the request to whatever layout you are using internally. It only means your http host name changes in the URL. But as said: using the internal proxy module you can even prevent that. See my answer below.

Comment: ok so how could i do that then. Then someone goes to www.mydomain.com/content/something - then in the folder "content" i have a htaccess wich will point to system.mydomain.com/content/variablepart and show the content? - if this is posible this would be good also

Comment: Did you even bother to _read_ my answer below? I explained all that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most elegant probably is to use apaches proxy module in combination with rewriting rules. That leaves the URL visible in the browser unchanged but internally proxies the requests between otherwise separate http hosts.

Use such a rule in the hosts `www.example.com` and/or `example.com` host:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?content/seo-name-of-item https://system.example.com/api [END,P]
```

The syntax should work in the real http host configuration or in `htaccess` style files. But a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using `.htaccess` style files. Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

If you get an internal server error with that (http status 500), you might have to replace the `END` flag with the older `L` flag.

You need validatable ssl certificates for the externally visible host name, so `www.example.com` and/or `example.com`.

You can also decide to use http internally, for the internal proxy connection, since ssl encryption does not really make sense there.

Oh, and obviously you need the proxy module installed.

An alternative would be to use the proxy module only. Take a look at the documentation and examples of the `ProxyPass` rule: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html

Comment: so when someone goes to system.mydomain.com/content/something - it wil show www.mydomain.com/content/something as url ?  also the  "something" part needs to be variable,

Comment: No. This allows someone entering `https://www.example.com/content/seo-name-of-item` to see that URL in the browser whilst it is processed and responded to by your setup on `https://system.example.com/api`.